# Problem insert textbox in database VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with insert textbox into the database.
I just want to create a user with the textbox and so my question is how to add the data from the textbox into the User table of my database ?

I redid all the code and found a simpler method but I have the following error showing "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid' User 'object name.' System .Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid' User 'object name.' " in the row **rs = SqlCommande.ExecuteReader()**

```
Dim CnxAppli As String = "Server=" & My.Settings.nomServeur & "; DataBase= " & My.Settings.nomBDD & "; Uid=" & My.Settings.idUser & "; Pwd=" & My.Settings.mdp & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim sqlConnect As New SqlConnection
    sqlConnect.ConnectionString = CnxAppli
    Dim SqlReq As String = "insert into Utlisateur (nom, prenom, tel, mail, poste, login, mdp) values ('" & tbNom.Text & "', '" & tbPrenom.Text & "', '" & tbTel.Text & "', '" & tbMail.Text & "', '" & tbPoste.Text & "', '" & tbLogin.Text & "', '" & tbMdp.Text & "')"
    Dim SqlCommande = New SqlCommand(SqlReq, sqlConnect)
    'SqlCommande.CommandText = SqlReq
    'SqlCommande.Connection = sqlConnect
    sqlConnect.Open()
    Dim rs As SqlDataReader
    rs = SqlCommande.ExecuteReader()
    rs.Close()
    sqlConnect.Close()
    GestionUtilisateurs.Show()
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You just said that you have a problem and dumped a bunch of code and expected us to figure it out. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem, which includes EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, EXACTLY how you're trying to achieve it, EXACTLY what happens when you try and EXACTLY how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I edited the ad. Is it good now?

Comment: Why would you be calling `Fill` when the point is to insert a record? I think you need to do a bit more reading on the fundamentals of ADO.NET.

Comment: Your classes are a bit of a mess. In MyFormulaire you have declared all your backer fields as String but your Properties are all Integer arrays. Since 2015 we have had Auto-Implemented properties. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties You should make assignments with data from outside the class directly to the properites not to the backer fields because there migh be code in the property set. Fix all this type mismatch and edit you code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I redid all the code but I still have a small error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.
For those who want the solution:

```
Dim CnxAppli As String = "Server=" & My.Settings.nomServeur & "; DataBase= " & My.Settings.nomBDD & "; Uid=" & My.Settings.idUser & "; Pwd=" & My.Settings.mdp & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim sqlConnect As New SqlConnection
    sqlConnect.ConnectionString = CnxAppli
    Dim cmSQL As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL = "insert into utilisateur(nom, prenom, tel, mail, poste, login, mdp) values('" & tbNom.Text & "','" & tbPrenom.Text & "','" & tbTel.Text & "','" & tbMail.Text & "','" & tbPoste.Text & "','" & tbLogin.Text & "','" & tbMdp.Text & "')"
    cmSQL = New SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnect)
    Dim DataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmSQL)
    Dim cmBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter)
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet()
    Dim DataTable As New DataTable

    sqlConnect.Open()
    cmSQL.Connection = sqlConnect

    DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "utilisateur")
    DataTable = DataSet.Tables("utilisateur")

    'cmSQL = New SqlCommand(strSQL, cnSQL)
    'cmSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

    sqlConnect.Close()

    GestionUtilisateurs.Show()
    Me.Close()
```